# MongoDb $where not accepting javascript function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In the MongoDb (v4.0) docs it says we can [pass a javascript function](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/query/where/#where) to a where clause. I would expect the following trivial example to return zero docs...

```
let receipts = 
    await db
        .collection<IReceipt>("receipt_txs")
        .find({$where: function () { return false; } } )
        .toArray();
```

However this returns every doc.

The following syntax works, but for *operational reasons* i would rather use the above syntax.

```
let receipts = 
    await db
        .collection<IReceipt>("receipt_txs")
        .find({$where: "function () { return false; }" } )
        .toArray();

let receipts = 
    await db
        .collection<IReceipt>("receipt_txs")
        .find({$where: "false" } )
        .toArray();
```

Can anyone help me to understand where I'm going wrong? The docs are quite clear, and this syntax has been [valid since v2](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/operator/query/where/#where) so I'm sure it can't be a bug.

Comment: Which language you are using? The first snippet will work only in javascript/mongo shell

Comment: I'm using typescript, hadnt considered the implications of the compile down, will check that now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations) with function literals is not compatible with all frameworks. For example it is a [feature request in Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6311#issuecomment-323180304) and not supported out of the box.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Pass a function in directly is only supported by the mongo shell. Thanks.